# apache camel - invalid credentials in aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-camel

How am I supposed to handle invalid access/secret key on camel?

I've tried the `errorHandler` of camel but turned out it's for error due to failed exchanges of message, whereas this issue occurred even before the exchanges.

I've tried the `pollingStrategy` as well, and I seem to be able to catch the error on `rollback()`.  My issue with this one is that it still kept on retrying even if the method return false.  I also needed to specify the delay between retries, would I need to implement this myself on my class implementing `PollingConsumerPollStrategy`?

```
@Override
public boolean rollback(Consumer consumer, Endpoint endpoint, int retryCounter, Exception e) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("retryCounter " + retryCounter);
    if (retryCounter < 3) {
        // return true to tell Camel that it should retry the poll immediately
        return true;
    }
    // okay we give up do not retry anymore
    return false;
}


14:20:26.406 WARN  o.a.c.component.aws.s3.S3Consumer [Camel (camelContext) thread #0 - aws-s3://thebucket] - log:224 - Consumer S3Consumer[aws-s3://thebucket?amazonS3Client=%23s3Client] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[aws-s3://thebucket?amazonS3Client=%23s3Client]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception - The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.]
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:659) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:347) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2994) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2965) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:481) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Consumer.poll(S3Consumer.java:69) ~[camel-aws-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187) [camel-core-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114) [camel-core-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
14:20:27.927 WARN  o.a.c.component.aws.s3.S3Consumer [Camel (camelContext) thread #0 - aws-s3://thebucket] - log:224 - Consumer S3Consumer[aws-s3://thebucket?amazonS3Client=%23s3Client] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[aws-s3://thebucket?amazonS3Client=%23s3Client]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception - The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.]
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:659) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:347) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2994) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2965) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:481) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Consumer.poll(S3Consumer.java:69) ~[camel-aws-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187) [camel-core-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114) [camel-core-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using camel 2.12.x or camel 2.13.0, you can try to set the URI option of [backoff*](https://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html#PollingConsumer-Usingbackofftolettheschedulerbelessaggressive).